# ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] in project root folder

Tags: hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file in the **project root folder**.

If I run an application containing:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

it crashes in the `configure()` method with the following message:

> Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]

**Output**:

```
Jun 17, 2016 12:04:59 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.0.Final}
Jun 17, 2016 12:04:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
Jun 17, 2016 12:04:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at o.k.j.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:22)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **hibernate.cfg.xml** file should be moved to **src** folder.

Comment: So i can not create a specify folder for my hibernate.cfg.xml file !

Answer (score 49):

If you are using Maven to build your project, place the 'hibernate.cfg.xml' file under 'src/main/resources'

Comment: After spending better part of an hour on maven clean, build, update and what not, this worked for me like a charm

Comment: How can I configure Maven to look for the file somewhere else?

Comment: I have the same issue, and it didn't help

Comment: However, when I ran clean and install afterwards (those are Maven lifecycle phases), it worked

Answer (score 16):

If you are using **Maven** as build tool then place `hibernate.cfg.xml` under **resources** folder.

*Steps to make application refer Hibernate Configuration File.*

Right click the **resources** folder and select **Mark Directory As** option and click on **Resources Root**.

These steps worked for me in **InteliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.**

Answer (score 3):

Moving `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to `src/main/resources` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Below solutions might work for **Maven, Intellij**

1. move "hibernate.cfg.xml" to resources folder -> rebuild project
   [image]
2. right-click on resources folder -> then unmark resources root -> mark it resources root again
   [image]

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using intellij IDEA. put the file in src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

Use forward / to put cfg file without forward / it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar issue, and I noticed that my hibernate configuration file "hibernate.cfg.xml" was not on the required path. Hence I moved hibernate.cfg.xml into src folder and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It must be added to the configuration file as a persistence type.

**Project Settings** > **Facets** > **Add Hibernate** > **Config Path**

And you can see it configured in **View** > **Tools Windows** > **Persistence**

GL

Answer (score 0):

[image: hibernate.cfg.xml]

if you are using eclipse then
It must be added to the configuration as
src\main\java\hibernate.cfg.xml