# Getting error "Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]"

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

I am not very familiar with hibernate framework and I came across a "problem".
So, I created a Hibernate (JPA) project in IntelliJ, succesfully connected it to a Postgress database and when I want to run the project I get this error.

This is Main.java code

```
import entity.Faculty;
import entity.Student;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Faculty ciocky = new Faculty();
        ciocky.setId(1);
        ciocky.setName("USV");

        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setAge(22);
        s1.setId(33);
        s1.setFaculty(ciocky);
        s1.setLastName("Ioanid");
        s1.setFirstName("Berariu");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(s1);

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

This is Student class:

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Student.byFacultyId", query = "select s from  Student s where s.faculty.id =?1")
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private Faculty faculty;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Student student = (Student) o;

        if (id != student.id) return false;
        if (age != student.age) return false;
        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(student.firstName) : student.firstName != null) return false;
        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(student.lastName) : student.lastName != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + age;
        return result;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "faculty_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Faculty getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }

    public void setFaculty(Faculty facultyByFacultyId) {
        this.faculty = facultyByFacultyId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", " + faculty +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is Faculty class

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Faculty {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Faculty faculty = (Faculty) o;

        if (id != faculty.id) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(faculty.name) : faculty.name != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Faculty{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro.cristi</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernateTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hibernateTest</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.29.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="default">

        <class>entity.Faculty</class>
        <class>entity.Student</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate_test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="******"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is the error:

```
Apr 24, 2021 11:05:15 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at Main.main(Main.java:68)
```

I know that it might sound as a dumb quesion but I am new, so please if you can help I am very gratefully.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource \[hibernate.cfg.xml\] in project root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879613/configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg-xml-resource-hibernate-cfg-xml-in)

Comment: I've already tried this. The problem is that I do not have this hibernate.cfg.xml to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)`

It was about the **.configure()** method which search for hibernate.cfg.xml file. As this file was not in my project, I found on internet that you can add `.setProperty()` in which you specify the data from hibernate.cfg.xml, so I removed it and added `.setProperty()` to my new Configuration.